# looping through a list, checking an item in the list being looped on using while vs if

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

example problem from a book

if i wanted to check through the list for `pastrami` and make sure no pastrami ended up in `finished`, this works fine:

```
orders = ['tuna sub', 'chicken parmasean', 'pastrami', 'chicken teryiaki', 'pastrami']
finished = []

for order in orders:
    while 'pastrami' in orders:
        orders.remove('pastrami')
    print("preparing " + order + " ...")
    finished.append(order)

for sandwich in finished:
    print(sandwich + " is ready")

└─$ python3 sandwiches.py
preparing tuna sub ...
preparing chicken parmasean ...
preparing chicken teryiaki ...
tuna sub is ready
chicken parmasean is ready
chicken teryiaki is ready
```

but using `if` to check `order` does not work.

```
orders = ['tuna sub', 'chicken parmasean', 'pastrami', 'chicken teryiaki', 'pastrami']
finished = []

for order in orders:
    if order == 'pastrami':
        orders.remove('pastrami')
    print("preparing " + order + " ...")
    finished.append(order)

for sandwich in finished:
    print(sandwich + " is ready")


─$ python3 sandwiches.py
preparing tuna sub ...
preparing chicken parmasean ...
preparing pastrami ...
preparing pastrami ...
tuna sub is ready
chicken parmasean is ready
pastrami is ready
pastrami is ready
```

I don't understand why this happens?

Comment: You print the order anyways, it will check and remove but `order` will still be saved as 'pastrami'

Comment: Never change list while iterating over it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Even the first one doesn't work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant to negate your `if`?

```py
finished = []

for order in orders:
    if order != 'pastrami':
        print("preparing " + order + " ...")
        finished.append(order)
```